# wc-api-java not able to get woocommerce orders using before and after param

Tags: java, api, woocommerce, get, woocommerce-rest-api

I want to get orders for the specific date but getting below error tried several date formates but getting the same error. This only happens when I am adding date parameters(before and after). This api works fine for per_page or without any param.

```
WooCommerce wooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI(config, ApiVersionType.V3);
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("per_page","10");
params.put("after","2016-11-20T13:57:31.2311892-04:00");
params.put("before","2017-11-20T13:57:31.2311892-04:00");

List<Map<String, Object>>  orders = wooCommerce.getAll(EndpointBaseType.ORDERS.getValue(), params);
```

This code is giving me an error
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't parse retrieved object: {code=woocommerce_rest_authentication_error, message=Invalid signature - provided signature does not match., data={status=401}}**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for the date issue here is the solution. we need to encode the dates.

```
params.put("after", percentEncode("01-01-2021T00:00:00"));

public String percentEncode(String s) {
        final String UTF_8 = "UTF-8";

        try {
            return URLEncoder.encode(s, UTF_8)
                    // OAuth encodes some characters differently:
                    .replace(SpecialSymbol.PLUS.getPlain(), SpecialSymbol.PLUS.getEncoded())
                    .replace(SpecialSymbol.STAR.getPlain(), SpecialSymbol.STAR.getEncoded())
                    .replace(SpecialSymbol.TILDE.getEncoded(), SpecialSymbol.TILDE.getPlain());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me just using this format 2021-07-01T11:51:36 helped.

Comment: 10/11/2021: I am still having issues with using the dates in the parameter fields of the woocommerece :get all orders call.  params.put("per_page","10");
params.put("after","2016-11-20T13:57:31.2311892-04:00");  and the answer from the post params.put("after", percentEncode("01-01-2021T00:00:00")); did not work.   I am getting the following error:

Comment: I am getting the following error:     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't parse retrieved object: {code=rest_invalid_param, message=Invalid parameter(s): after, data={status=400, params={after=Invalid date.}, details={after={code=rest_invalid_date, message=Invalid date., data=null}}}}
 at com.icoderman.woocommerce.DefaultHttpClient.getEntityAndReleaseConnection(DefaultHttpClient.java:127).